# How to hit codeigniter API from an alias domain?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, server

I have a REST API project built in condeigniter 3 in `www.mysiteone.com/project` which works fine. Now, another domain of mine is `www.mysitetwo.com/project` is configured such way that it hits the first url. For example, if I browse `www.mysitetwo.com/project/license.txt` it shows the file that is in `www.mysiteone.com/project/license.txt` as it should. But the issue is when I am trying to access any of the APIs. Like `www.mysiteone.com/project/apiendpoint` returns data but when I am hitting `www.mysitetwo.com/project/apiendpoint` it is showing the following error:

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>404 Not Found</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Not Found</h1>
    <p>The requested URL /srv/www/mysiteone.com/www/project/index.php/apiendpoint was not found on this server.
    </p>
</body>

</html>
```

here is the .htaccess file inside the project folder

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

And in config.php

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
```

Where should I make change to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

Need to replace

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

With

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /project/index.php/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Below will be more effective so as to handle possible future scenarios.

```sh
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond "%{HTTP_HOST}"    "!^www\.mysitetwo\.com" [NC]
RewriteCond "%{HTTP_HOST}"    "!^$"
RewriteRule "^/?(.*)"         "http://www.mysiteone.com/$1" [L,R,NE]
```